# Using the same variable in many classes / Sharing variables across classes 

Tags: dart

Something like I'm get CanvasRenderingContext2D and CanvasElement in one class, but how to use my CanvasRenderingContext2D in other classes?

```
class Unnamed {
    CanvasElement c;
    CanvasRenderingContext ctx;

    Unnamed() {
        this.c = query('#canvas');
        this.ctx = this.c.getContext('2d');
    }
}
```

And how to use my ctx from Unnamed class in other classes? Something like:

```
class Box {
    num x,
        y;

    Box() {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void draw() {
        myCtxFromUnnamedClass.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 64, 64);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English language.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to pass CanvasRenderingContext2D as a parameter of method draw.

```
class Box {
    num x, y;

    Box() {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void draw(CanvasRenderingContext ctx) {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 64, 64);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! But this is only way?

Comment: No, this is not the only way.
But I recommend you pass the context as a parameter, this way you avoid Box dependency with Unnamed and will be more easy to test Box alone using unit tests for example.

Answer (score 0):

First, your Box() won't compile as no `x` and `y` are supplied to the `Box()` constructor.

And

```
 void draw(CanvasRenderingContext ctx) {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 64, 64);
    }
```

doesn't make any sense if you pass `ctx` as `Box`' constructor parameter. But to answer your question:

```
void main() { 
  Unnamed unnamed = new Unnamed();
  Box box = new Box(unnamed.ctx, 0, 0);
  box.draw();
}

class Unnamed {
  CanvasElement c;
  CanvasRenderingContext ctx;

  Unnamed() : c = query('#canvas') { // variable initialization should be done this way
    this.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  }
}

class Box {
  num x, y;
  CanvasRenderingContext myCtxFromUnnamedClass;

  Box(this.myCtxFromUnnamedClass, this.x, this.y); // this is an idiomatic Dart constructor

  void draw() {
    myCtxFromUnnamedClass.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 64, 64);
  }
}
```